# How do I enable and limit field permission to a specific user?

Tags: entities, users

I have created a content type that contains 8 fields.

Users can view the content as a table from search filter in views.

The next step is that I would like to:

1. Enable specific users of a particular role to edit only 1 of the 8 fields.
2. They can only edit the field once.

Is there a way to do this with minimal PHP Coding? i.e. use of modules such as field permission etc. or rules?

Comment: create a new role, give user that role?

Comment: thing is, i have been able to limit access to a particular role X but i would like to refine the access further to only specific users (e.g. User A). Essentially i do not want to filter by role, i would like to filter by user. Ive been trying to work out a way either via referencing the user or having some common term reference etc. but ive not managed to work out a solution.